# BigQuery Java client - how to query external ( federated ) table?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, external-tables, federated-table

I am using the new google-cloud-bigquery and google-cloud-storage api. I want to query an external table, which I created like this:

```
ExternalTableDefinition etd = ExternalTableDefinition.newBuilder(bucketPath, schema, FormatOptions.csv()).build();
TableId tableID = TableId.of(dataset, targetTableName);
TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableID, etd).build();
```

Now I want to query this table, but to have it as a temporary one, using the QueryRequest:

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.newBuilder("select * from table limit 10 ").setUseLegacySql(true).setDefaultDataset(dataset).build();
QueryResponse response = client.query(queryRequest);
```

But it fails due to a table not exists, which makes sense. I am trying to do something similar to this command line:

```
bq query --project_id=<project ID> --external_table_definition=wikipedia::/tmp/wikipedia 'select name from wikipedia where name contains "Alex";'
```

but in Java.

To summarize: how do I create and query an **external** **temporary** table through Java client for big query?

Reference from documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#temporary-tables

Comment: Did you fin a solution , I have a similar use case ?

Comment: Posted as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, here is the way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

BigQuery bigquery = 
BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();


ExternalTableDefinition etd = 
ExternalTableDefinition.newBuilder("gs://", createSchema(), 
FormatOptions.csv()).build();

TableId tableId = TableId.of("testdataset", "mytablename");


bigquery.create(TableInfo.newBuilder(tableId, etd).build());


//Now query the table project.testdataset.mytablename

}
```